# Repeating the indefinite article

Tags: indefinite-article, ellipsis

Repeating the indefinite article. Is it a matter of style? If so, which quote is more natural [or maybe sounds better]?

> My name is Amy Purdy, I am a survivor, snowboarder, founder of
>   Adaptive Action Sports, globetrotter and daydreamer.

vs.

> My name is Amy Purdy, I am a survivor, a snowboarder, a founder of
>   Adaptive Action Sports, a globetrotter and a daydreamer.

Source: Amy Purdy
Note: the first comma is from the source. It should be replaced by a period.

Comment: I've observed that compositions with the 'a' repeated are often used to highlight contrast, and compositions without the 'a' repeated are often used to demonstrate similarity. Compare: *I got a BA, Masters, and PhD all from State University* with *I've been a lineman, a sailor, a mechanic, and a musician.* My observation may be anecdotal. I've never seen this expressed as a rule (like adjective order), or it would be an answer and not a comment.

Comment: Thanks. My observation may be anecdotal. I've never seen this expressed as a rule (like adjective order), or it would be an answer and not a comment.

Comment: You could use the colon. _Hello, I'm Amy Purdy: survivor, snowboarder, founder of Adaptive Action Sports, globetrotter, and daydreamer._

Answer (score 1):

Including or omitting the indefinite article is entirely a matter of personal style.  In some cases it *sounds* better to include it, to help emphasize the individual elements of a list.

> In the picnic basket he carefully packed **an** apple, **a** pear, **a** bottle of wine, **a** round of cheese, a dish of pâté, a pat of butter, and **a** freshly-baked baguette, as well as **a** corkscrew, **a** sharp knife (for the fruit and the cheese), **a** serrated knife (for the bread), a blunt knife (for the pâté and the butter), **a** small china plate, **a** silver fork, and **a** single, long-stemmed wine glass.

Note how the repetitive article makes it clear there is *one* of each object.  It also helps reinforce the impression that the subject is a *meticulous* person who has carefully chosen each of the items in the basket.

Remove the repetitive article, and the sentence sounds more hurried and careless:

> In the basket he tossed an apple, pear, bottle of wine, round of cheese, dish of pâté, pat of butter, and a freshly-baked baguette.

There are many other reasons why a writer may choose to repeat the article, but the best way to learn these is to read copiously.