# Do I need to put a second article after "and" in the sentence "I am a songwriter and author."?

Tags: grammar, articles

Do I need to put a second article after "and" in the sentence "I am a songwriter and author."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeating the indefinite article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149321/repeating-the-indefinite-article)

Comment: Thank you, quite relevant, it's not only repeating thin, it's also the need of different articles. Like can I say, "I ate an apple and banana" OR should I say "I ate an apple and a banana" Also what if the articles were the same, then could we omit? "I ate an apple and egg"?

Comment: The indefinite article has two different "realizations" in writing: *a* and *an*. These words aren't different articles, it's the same article, just pronounced a bit differently when followed by a vowel sound. Therefore, a single indefinite article suffices, regardless of its "realization".

Comment: What do you mean by "realization"? So "I ate an apple and banana" and "I ate an apple and egg" are both fine?  If I add the extra articles, would it be wrong?

Comment: "an egg" and "a big egg" both use the indefinite article. It's just that the spelling and pronunciation (the "realisation") depends on the sound immediately after it when spoken (not the spelling). Note that "an big egg" is completely wrong because "big" starts with a consonant sound, not a vowel sound. In regards to _If I add the extra articles, would it be wrong?_, the linked question fully answers your question.

Comment: thank yo, the linked question doesnt answer in cases where the next indefinite article differs from the first one, whether we should use it or can omit it. so to make things clear Dennis, should I say "I am a songwriter and an author"? or CAN I also say "I am a songwriter and author"?